# SQL JOIN ON(with two conditions)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

i want to know if is possible to write a SQL ORACLE command joining two tables with two CASE WHEN in the on() condition; I tried this way; but it didnt work

```
SELECT *
FROM A  a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B b
       ON ((CASE
                WHEN LENGTH (a.xxx) = 3
                THEN a.xxx
                WHEN LENGTH (a.yyy) = 2
                THEN TO_CHAR (a.xxx || TRUNC (a.zzz, 'YY'))
            END) **=**
           (CASE
                WHEN LENGTH (a.xxx) = 3 THEN b.wert
                WHEN LENGTH (a.xxx) = 2 THEN b.bez
            END));
```

Comment: Oracle has no operator `**=**`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the logic that you want?

```
on (length(a.xxx) = 3 and a.xxx = b.wert) or
   (length(a.xxx) = 2 and (a.xxx || TRUNC(a.zzz, 'YY')) = b.bez)
```

`case` expressions are not normally needed for boolean expressions.

Comment: it doesnt work; i become a ORA-00920: invalid relational Operator ERROR

Comment: @LinkiLinki . . . There was a missing closing paren.